# When fetching friends and friends of friends via FQL, how to ignore private friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Here my FQL request :

> $fql_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
>      . 'fql?q={"friends":"SELECT+uid,third_party_id,name,sex,pic,work+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+uid+IN(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me())",'
>      . '"friends+of+friends":"SELECT+uid,name,sex,pic,work+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+uid+IN(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+IN(SELECT+uid+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+uid+IN(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me())))"}'
>      . '&' . $access_token;

When all user have a "public" friends list, all is fine. But if someone's friends list is set to "private" then it crash.

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "Can't lookup all friends of 593606920 due to user's privacy settings.",
>         "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",
>         "code": 604
>      }
>   }

How can I "ignore" private friends list and only take all other ?